# Java - Using reflection to attach data to object if its type matches a string

Tags: java, class, reflection

So here's a question for you java experts.

I have some definitions I keep in text files, let's say they're properties files. I have a wide variety of different objects all of which implement an interface, we'll call it `Cardable`. It guarantees methods to attach these definitions and retrieve them for display within the application.

```
public interface Cardable {
   public void attach(Card c);
   public Card retrieve();
}
```

Now, when I build the static list(s) of these objects, whose types vary, I see if the type matches a set of classes declared in the definition like so

```
Thing.Bag.LeatherBag= ... (definitions)
```

If we are creating this class (definition condensed to show the idea)

```
public class LeatherBag extends Bag {
   ...
}

public class Bag extends Thing {
   ...
}

public class Thing implements Cardable {
   ...
}
```

The process is to go through the list during the pre-loading phase and assign the most specific card to a given class. This would be defined arbitrarily as, for instance, more classes specified (Thing.Bag.LeatherBag would be more specific than Bag.LeatherBag by this rule.)

Once I break the class names out of the string, how would I go about using instanceof to check if the object (once we verify it implements `Cardable`) is an instance of all of the specified classes ? Instanceof seems to pertain to types, but not to Strings containing type/class names.

Comment: `...if the object (once we verify it implements Cardable)` To check if some object is instance of class that implements Cardable you can use `Cardable.class.isInstance(yourObject)`. You can also use `Class.forName("full.name.of.YourClass").isInstance(yourObject)` to check if it is type of `YourClass`, but be carefull since it will also return true for `superclass.isInstance(subClass)`.

Comment: Pshemo, that should be an answer...!

Comment: I have a feeling that my comment answers only part of your question so I decided to not post it as answer. If you want you can create your own full answer based on my comment and accept it. I don't mind :)

Comment: so something like `public boolean hasClasses(String [] cnames, Object o) { for(String s : cnames) { if(!Class.forName(s).isInstance(o)) { return false; } } return true; }` ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a class represented by its string name, and you want to determine if it implements a set of interfaces represented by their string names and if it extends a set of classes represented by their string names.  You can do this with the [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) class.

```
void isValid(String className) {
    Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
    Class[] interfaces = clazz.getInterfaces();
    ArrayList<Class> superclasses = new ArrayList<>();
    Class temp = clazz.getSuperclass();
    superclasses.add(temp);
    while(temp != Object.class) {
        temp = temp.getSuperclass();
        superclasses.add(temp);
    }
}
```

This should leave you with `interfaces` holding all of the class's interfaces, and `superclasses' holding all of the class's superclasses.  You can call Class#getName on these class objects and compare them to the string representations of your interfaces / classes to see if the class in question meets your criteria.

Comment: I've complicated it a bit = does `Class.forName(className)` give you a type you can then use `instanceof` with against an `Object` to see if the unknown typed object is an instance of that class?

Comment: You can use [isInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29), as in `Class clazz = Class.forName(className); clazz.isInstance(object);`